# Gradle Managed Devices - Bluetooth keeps stopping

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-espresso, gradle-managed-device

When running gradle managed devices via

```
./gradlew pixel4api32DebugAndroidTest -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.class=com.xxx.xxx.xxx.Suites.CITestSuite -Pandroid.experimental.androidTest.numManagedDeviceShards=2 --enable-display --info
```

it opens the emulators but for API 32 and API 33, I keep getting this Bluetooth keeps stopping error message.  How can this be handled?

[image]

This happens with emulator version 33.1.20 (Android Studio HedgeHog RC2).  This does NOT happen with emulator version 32.1.15 (Android Studio Giraffe).

It also gives these crash report popups:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This was actually an issue with a particular emulator version and the android developers fixed it:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/308840222